# auto complete does not work at all in eclipse

Tags: linux, eclipse, autocomplete, eclipse-cdt

Hey I'm having troubles to make auto complete work on my eclipse Indigo 3.7.2.
Os: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
It does not work at all, even to my own files that are in the project and compile just fine.
I have googled this issue and found several optional solutions, I tried adding include path's like:
/usr/include/c++/*
(even though I don't think this should solve the problem since it does not work even with my files)
to the project setting, I have try re-building the indexer, I even re-installed eclipse, nothing seems to help.

Did anyone here encountered this problem and found a fix?

Comment: Are you using a special window manager? I have trouble using eclipse together with ctwm since the event handling in Java works poorly together with the virtual desktops. I get, what I assume, is the same problem as you get with auto completion not working properly.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was solved by installing eclipse manually rather than using the package manager. I guess there is a bug in the package manager version when using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by installing eclipse manually rather than using the package manager. 
I guess there is a bug in the default package manager version when using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.